How should the name and location of the ssh key file be specified in the yml file for drush remote setup?
I want to run drush on a remote server.
e.g.
drush @live status
where @live is the remote server.
I believe I need to make use of my existing ssh key pair to be able to do this.  I already use my ssh key pair to connect to the server to login and also for github to pull and push to my remote repo.
Here is an example drush yml set up file:
live:
  host: server.domain.com
  user: www-admin
  root: /other/path/to/live/drupal
  uri: http://example.com 
stage:
  host: server.domain.com
  user: www-admin
  root: /other/path/to/stage/drupal
  uri: http://stage.example.com

I would like to use an ssh key-pair with a name different from the default /home/<USERNAME>/.ssh/id_rsa.
Therefore I am hoping that in the yml file I can just do this:
ssh:
  IdentityFile: /my/path/to/my/sshkey

Can I?
Reference for running drush on remote server, via my local:
https://www.drush.org/13.x/site-aliases/

An alternative would be simply to add an entry to ~/.ssh/config for the relevant host

Good point @Clive I'll try that!

You can achieve this using options label and passing -i /path/to/id_rsa
live:
  host: server.domain.com
  user: www-admin
  root: /other/path/to/live/drupal
  uri: http://example.com
  ssh:
    options: -i /path/to/live/id_rsa
stage:
  host: server.domain.com
  user: www-admin
  root: /other/path/to/stage/drupal
  uri: http://stage.example.com
  ssh:
    options: -i /path/to/stage/id_rsa

You can find more info here: https://www.drush.org/12.x/site-aliases/#additional-site-alias-options

+1 upvote thank you @pablo Nicolas. I'm likely to mark this answer as accepted, after trying it out.  Clive's comment to provide a solution is also good.  But an advantage of your answer is that the server addresses only need to be maintained in the yml file and not also the config file. Both answers are great though.

This is definitely the better solution; my comment was just an alternative, and it won’t be practical for everyone, whereas this answer applies for everyone
